# How do you sort a String List by the number of words count in c#

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to sort a String List by the number of word count

```
var list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("The quick brown"); // 5
    list.Add("brown fox jumps over");   // 4
    list.Add("quick brown fox jumps over the lazy");    //1
    list.Add("The quick brown fox jumps")   // 3
    list.Add("fox jumps over the lazy dog");        // 2

foreach(var item in list)
{
 console.Writeline(item);
}
```

Is there a way to generate an output without using another list or for loop to sort

```
quick brown fox jumps over the lazy
fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps
brown fox jumps over
The quick brown
```

Comment: What have you tried? You know the correct output but posted code that does not get you there. For instance if you relax your restrictions about "another list or for loop" can you implement the logic?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the string cannot be null, below should work.

```
foreach(var item in list.OrderByDescending(q => q.Split(' ').Length))
{
    console.Writeline(item);
}
```

Comment: `Split` returns a `string[]` so you could use `Length` here instead of `Count()`.

Comment: Awesome! it was too quick . Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by number of words:

```
list.Sort((a, b) => b.Split(' ').Length - a.Split(' ').Length);
```

Or if you want to sort just by string length (which could be what you want as well)

```
list.Sort((a, b) => b.Length - a.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Sort method:

```
your_list.Sort((x,y)=>y.Split(' ').Length - x.Split(' ').Length);

your_list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to encapsulate the logic in a slighty more reusable manner, implement the [`IComparer<T>` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx), like so.

```
public class WordCountComparer : IComparer<String>
{
    public Int32 Compare(String a, String b)
    {
        var split = new[] { ' ' };

        var aCount = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a) ? 0 : a.Split(split).Length;
        var bCount = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(b) ? 0 : b.Split(split).Length;

        if (aCount == bCount) { return 0; }
        if (aCount < bCount) { return 1; } else { return -1; }
    }
}
```

You can pass an instance of your class directly to the [`List<T>.Sort` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx), and it'll sort the list in-place.

```
list.Sort(new WordCountComparer());
```